# turtlebot_teleop Logitech

Tags: ros, joystick, logitech

[image: Rosanswers logo]

turtlebot_teleop not working with Logitech joystick

Logitech joystick connected
roslaunch turtlebot_teleop logitech.launch
rostopic echo /joy

Does not change when I move the joystick. Any missing step?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172892/turtlebot_teleop-logitech/) by [pnambiar](https://answers.ros.org/users/15286/pnambiar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2014-06-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-06-05**:
Hi @pnambiar, I think you need to execute some command like a playstation3 on the web( http://ros.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/roswiki/turtlebot_teleop%282f%29Tutorials%282f%29PS3%2820%29Joystick%2820%29Teleop.html ).

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-06-05**:
Is your joystick connected with workstation? I think joystick is used instead of keyboard, because you need kind of like driver to communicate with your turtlebot. I have moved a turtlebot with PS3joystick.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-06-06**:
@pnambiar, Could you tell me more detailed information about your using joystick? I think there is a few information on ROS tutorial too. Does your joystick have either a USB cable or USB wireless? I think it doesn't have a bluetooth.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-06-09**:
@pnambiar, I think you should write your answer. Please inform all of your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Hoystick has a usb cable. The problem is actually solved. I was using it on a windows machine with though a virtual box and I gould not get it to work. But on a linus machine it seems to work work. No additional steps needed.

---

Originally posted by [pnambiar](https://answers.ros.org/users/15286/pnambiar/) with karma: 120 on 2014-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0